# Why does it take so long to display a single string value in Python on Databricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a program that analyzes various schedules and I am wanting to display the schedule that is being ran.  To get the schedule name, I have a simple spark.sql string:

```
mySchedName=spark.sql("""
SELECT distinct schedule_name FROM 
global_temp.rawSchedDataTemp
""")
```

This takes .05 seconds to run.  When I try to print() or show() the value, it takes almost 5 minutes.  The data set is not that big (~ 100,000 rows).  I am sure that there is an underlying process that is going on, but should it really take this long to pull a single value?  The larger issue is that I need to pull other single values from this data set (min and max values) to use up line, but those take just as long when I go to put those values into a variable.  Is there a more efficient way to achieve this goal?

Comment: its taken long because you are using `distinct`

Comment: but the query runs in .03 seconds.  why does it take so long to view the value after it is assigned to the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark uses lazy evaluation for its rdds. Meaning that when you "run" the sql query it does not execute it on its compute nodes until an ACTION is called such as `print()` or `show()`.

The .05s running time is simply for declaring the DAG for running the query, the computation is done when `print()` is called.

https://understandingbigdata.com/spark-lazy-evaluation/